# Aws postgres Deadlock not written to server log

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, deadlock

I am seeing deadlocks on aurora postgres monitoring metrics. However when searching for the deadlock in the postgres log files, the information cannot be found. Is this an issue arising from min_log_level setting?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say if Amazon hacked up anything in that area, but with normal PostgreSQL, the only way for a deadlock not to show up in the log is if `log_min_messages` is set to `log`, `fatal` or `panic`.

Comment: Hi Laurenz, I see some deadlock messages but it seems intermittent ie not every deadlock that shows on the monitoring metrics is captured on log. The log_min_messages is set to engine default which I think is warning. Would you be able to advise

Comment: No, you'll probably have to ask Amazon what they did.

Comment: Hi Laurenz, our log_min_messages is set to `log` and it is not logged either. We will increase the log level to error. PostgreSQL version is 14.7

Comment: @UmutTEKİN Ah, I forgot `log`. Thanks for the correction.